# How to calculate incremental spend between two groups in a datafarme for a certain time period

Tags: python, r, pandas, numpy, data-analysis

I have a big data frame with the following information, with column day shows the date in `dd/mm/yy` format. For example, as following,

```
   UserID     group       day  sp       PU          new
0     213      test   6/10/14   4  $628.14     test-Red
1     314   control   6/10/14  15   $29.98      control
2     354      test  13/10/14   4  $554.58  test-NonRed
3    2131     test1  13/10/14   2   $60.41     test-Red
4     314  control1  13/10/14   1    $8.71      control
5     354     test1  20/10/14   1  $165.63  test-NonRed
```

I need to calculate the incremental spend in 6 weeks for the total test group (test-Red and test-NonRed) versus the control group. I need to show the result in absolute $ or %. 
What I have tried,

```
df.groupby(by=['PU','day']).sum().groupby(level=[0]).cumsum()
```

This gives me absolute sum for groups for each group, but
the excepted answer is something like this, with % also for each group

```
Control             $# 
Test - NonRed       $# 
Test - Red          $#
Total Result        $#
```

Any help would be great

Comment: Tried `pd.Series.cumsum`?

Comment: why do u have this tagged `r` ?

Comment: Any solutions in r or python is good for me,

Comment: what is your expected out put

Comment: My expected output is incremental spend for total test group versus the control group in absolute $ or % for 3 weeks as mentioned for  dummy data frame.

Comment: @user1017373 it is better show your expect output with data rather than the wording .

Comment: @Wen yes I sowed it in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need few steps to get there

```
df.PU=df.PU.str[1:].astype(float)
df.day=pd.to_datetime(df.day)
new1=pd.pivot_table(df,index='new',columns='day',values='PU',aggfunc=sum,fill_value=0,margins=True)
new1=new1.drop('All',1)
new1.cumsum(1)
Out[263]: 
day          2014-06-10 00:00:00  2014-10-13 00:00:00  2014-10-20 00:00:00
new                                                                       
control                    29.98                38.69                38.69
test-NonRed                 0.00               554.58               720.21
test-Red                  628.14               688.55               688.55
All                       658.12              1281.82              1447.45
```

Comment: Thanks for the result, but I need both % and sum in absolute numbers, I tried it in groupby as, In_spend.groupby(by=['PU','day']).sum().groupby(level=[0]).cumsum(), which give me absolute numbers, but then I dont have sum for each group with my solution

Comment: @user1017373 change the aggfunc to `pct_change`

Comment: Thanks sorry there is a small edit in my primary question the incremental spend for each group, that is for test (test-Red, and test-NonRed) versus control